# Maximum of absolute value of linear combinations with i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, random-variables

Suppose $x_{1},\dots,x_{n}$ are i.i.d random variables with density
$p(x_{i})=exp(-|x_{i}|)/2$. Denote column vector $x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n})^{T}$

Let $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix with unit euclidean norm rows
$c_{i}^T$ representing linear combinations.

Define $w(C)=\mathbb{E}_{x}\{\max_{j\in[n]}|c_{j}^Tx|\}$

Which $C$ maximizes $w(C)$?

Comment: How do you know that $C^*=I$ maximizes $w(C)$?

Comment: @Did - it was an assumption after some experimenting. I'm actually unsure. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

This does not fully answer your question, but it might be helpful. You can write $\mathbf{x}=r \mathbf{u}$ such that $r$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n-1)!}$  and $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector uniformly sampled from the surface of the unit $\ell_1$ ball. With independece of $r$ and $\mathbf{u}$, and using the fact that linear (and in general convex) functions attain their maximum on the boundary of their domain, you can reduce your problem in finding $C$ that maximizes $\mathbb{E}_\mathbf{u}\left[\sup_{\mathbf{c}\in\mathcal{P}}\mathbf{c}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u}\right]$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is the convex hull of $\lbrace\mathbf{c}_i\rbrace_{i=1}^n$. So, basically you want to find a polytope with $n$ vertices inscribed in the unit Euclidean ball such that it has maximum width in the sense defined above. I'm not sure if you can solve this exactly, but using symmetries of $\ell_1$ ball you might be able to find some properties of $\mathcal{P}$. For instance, I guess $\mathcal{P}$ would be invariant under permutation.

**Correction**: Since $r=\Vert \mathbf{x}\Vert_1$ is the sum of $n$ iid $\text{Exp(1)}$ random variables, it should have $\text{Erlang}(n,1)$ distribution itself rather than exponential.

Comment: If x=ru, wouldn't that make the coordinates of x dependent? They would all have the same $l1$ norm.

Comment: @Leo On the second thought, my decomposition doesn't have the problem you thought, but it is not correct anyways. The density functions of $x$ and $ru$ don't seem to be the same.

Comment: perhaps it's not the same but I think there should exist r such that $x=ru$ (in probability). After all, you can view x as first picking a "contour line" and then randomizing within that contour. So your conclusions are still valid, aren't they?

Comment: Well, I hoped for that as well, but $r$ and $u$ must be independent so that I can get rid of $r$ later on.

Comment: I think they are independent. You can calculate $P(r)$ by integrating over the contour of $x$ at distance $r$. So define such $r$ and take the same independent $u$ as in your answer. I believe $x$ does equal $ru$. What do you think?

Comment: The density of $r$ would be integral of the density of $x$ over the points with $\Vert x\Vert _1=r$. I don't see how this ends up being equal to the exponential distribution I was hoping for.

Comment: $r$ may not be exponential, but it is independent of $u$ and can be gotten rid of, which is the goal I believe.

Comment: That should be correct. I'll see if I can find the correct distribution. Then I'll be 100% sure.

Comment: Any idea how to show $w(C)\leq\mathbb{E}_{u}\{\|u\|_{\infty}\}$ for any $C$?

Comment: I'm not sure if that bound holds, but if an upper bound suffices, you can apply the Hölder's inequality to the inner product inside the supremum. However, I doubt that you'll end up with a sharp bound.

Comment: If this bound holds, then $C*=I$, which is my guess. Holder indeed is not tight enough I'm afraid. An argument that "looks" across the expectation is needed, rather than per element.

Comment: One thing that might work is to bound the expectation with probabilities. Something similar to Markov's inequality but not exactly itself (Markov's inequality particularly doesn't work as it doesn't give inequality in direction we want.)